# Get branch name whose associated JIRA status closed

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

**Is it possible to get git branch names who's associated JIRA status is closed ?**

I need this for cleaning up branches created from JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible given you have mentioned jira id in commit messages of that branch.

On the right side of jira ticket , there is a section named "Development", it will show you branch , commits and pull request information related to this jira.